# Web service in servlet - @WebServiceRef annotation gives 500 error.

Tags: java, servlets, soap, wsdl, tomcat7

After playing around with example SOAP application Calculator from NetBeans, I began making my own app, using some third-party WSDL's as service models.

I managed to successfully create a web service classes from this WSDL, unfortunately, when I try to inject this service into my servlet (called ClientServlet), I got 500 error

> "javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class clients.ClientServlet".

The service interface methods are defined in Interface class MyServiceInterface. Don't ask me why it is that way - this service is made by third party.

When I comment out this annotation, and subsequent field declaration, then it works (but I can't use this service).

My code snippet:

```
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="url/to/wsdl/of/my/service.wsdl")
public MyServiceInterface service;
```

Of course, I tried to do this without dependency injection, by direct creation of the instance of this class:

```
service1 = new MyService().getMyService();
```

MyService.java was created during importing a service from WSDL. GetMyService() method should return instance of the class that is implementing MyServiceInterface. But instead, Java throws me

> exception at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92)

I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0 and Netbeans 7.0 IDE. What I should do now?

Comment: Maybe you ought to post the entire stack trace. It is difficult for anyone to debug this failure without one that pinpoints the failure accurately. Even if you don't find anything useful in the stacktrace, someone who has worked with JAX-WS in the past will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - I just made it from scratch using GlassFish 3.1 server.

Comment: It seems chaning the server/container is the only solution.